# View gets resized when using PartialCurl model transition

Tags: uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller, viewwillappear

Ok so I'm trying to recreate the partial fold animation like in the standard google maps app on the iphone where the toolbar at the bottom stays where it is, but the views above it curl and such. Here are some images:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjTx6.png

(Wont let me put in hyperlinks for some reason <_<)

http: // i.imgur.com/lc9ig.png
http: // i.imgur.com/hqMlN.png

As you can see, the white view is sized correctly (320x416, point: (0,0)), and gets flipped up. The toolbar stays where it is. When focus returns back to the white view, it resizes itself (320x460, point: (0,-22)).

I have added viewWillAppear, viewWillDissapear, viewDidAppear and viewDidDissapear to the white view class and none of those methods ever get called (which is weird because I would assume the appear ones would be called when the view is first initialized).

Here is where I initialize the white view:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
 mapController = [[MapViewController alloc] init]; 
 mapController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
 [self.view addSubview:mapController.view];
}
```

and this is what happens when you hit the curl button:

```
- (IBAction)curlPage:(id)sender {
 SettingsViewController *settingsController = [[[SettingsViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
 settingsController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
 [mapController presentModalViewController:settingsController animated:YES];
}
```

So I guess my question is: When the control returns to the white view (mapController) what methods get called where I can manually resize the view back to the size I want it at, or is there a way I can stop it from resizing itself.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well I ended up figuring out the answer to this. Im not sure why it was being resized, but setting the frame manually in `viewWillDissapear` seemed to fix the problem.